# Is there an API service cheaper than Google Maps?

Tags: web-services, google-maps, cloud, bing-maps

Using the Google Maps Api or Bing Api on an internal site has a **minimum** cost of 5 figures per year (USD).

Are there any less expensive options to do the following?

- Geocode an address to get longitude and latitude
- Given 10 addresses, find a driving route through them

In our case, only US data would be required.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the Bing Maps Locations API (for geocoding) and Routes API (for routefinding) then you only pay for billable transactions that you incur - there's no minimum cost.

Technical reference here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701722.aspx

Sign up for a key at: http://www.bingmapsportal.com

Comment: Not correct - Any site that is not public facing is considered enterprise, which requires the 5 figure up front payment.  http://www.microsoft.com/maps/product/licensing_for_enterprise.aspx